# How to access net displacements in pyiron

Tags: pyiron

Using pyiron, I want to calculate the mean square displacement of the ions in my system. How do I see the total displacement (i.e. not folded back by periodic boundary conditions) without dumping very frequently and checking when an atom passes over the boundary and gets wrapped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to compare `job['output/generic/unwrapped_positions'][-1]` and `job.structure.positions+job.output.total_displacements[-1]`. If they deliver the same values, it's definitely fine both ways. If not, you can post the relevant lines in your notebook here.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add a few comments to Jan's answer:

While `job['output/generic/unwrapped_positions']` returns the unwrapped positions parsed from the output files, `job.output.total_displacements` returns the displacement of atoms calculated from each pair of consecutive snapshots. So if an atom moves more than half the box length in any direction, `job.output.total_displacements` will give wrong coordinates. Therefore, `job['output/generic/unwrapped_positions']` is generally more trustworthy, but it is not available in all the codes (since some codes simply do not provide an output for unwrapped positions).

Moreover, if an interactive job is used, it is possible that `job.structure.positions` does not return the initial positions, i.e. `job.structure.positions+job.output.total_displacements` won't be initial positions + displacements.

So, in short, my answer to your question would be rather "Use `job['output/generic/unwrapped_positions']` and if it's not available, use `job.structure.positions+job.output.total_displacements` but be aware of potential problems you might be running into."